Different errors with and without exception handling (Python psycopg2 UniqueViolation vs InternalError)
I'm familiar with coding and bit of front and backend development on existing projects, but fairly new to Python and postgreSql. I'm transferring 60GB or so of .csv files into a postgres db. I've been mostly successful, but a few of the .csv files failed to transfer and were passed over. I would like to comb back through all the .csv files to verify each row was transferred into the db, then move the 100% transferred .csv files into an archive.
Without any exception handling, a very telling psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation appears in the console, indicating duplicate primary keys.
Code:
cur.execute(query)
Output:
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "<table_name>_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key ("time")=(2003-10-01 00:00:06.146) already exists.
With exception handling, I am unable to catch a UniqueViolation, which appears to be a subtype of IntegrityError, pgcode=23505. Instead, I catch a InFailedSqlTransaction, which is a subtype of InternalError, pgcode=25P02
Code w/ exception handling:
try:
        cur.execute(query)
    except pg.errors.UniqueViolation as e:
        print(f"UniqueViolation: {data=}, {e=}")
        return False
    except InternalError as e:
        print(f"InternalError: {data=}, {e.pgcode=}, {e.diag.message_primary=}")
        return False

Output:
InternalError: data="'2003-10-01 01:59:47.883000',1.16751,1.16741,28400000,31700001", e.pgcode='25P02', e.diag.message_primary='current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block'
Problem:
I would like to catch the UniqueViolation so that I can implement an intelligent reaction.

Once you get an integrity error (such as UniqueViolation) the transaction is in a broken state. See the linked dupicates for ways to fix this.

Thanks! That first duplicate wasn't coming up in my searches.
